# Form API + Module: Nested default value variable_get doesnt behave the same as unnested variable_get

Tags: 7, forms, configuration

Heres the example code:

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form['nest'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Nested settings'),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['nest']['nested_example_item'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Nested Example Item'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('nested_example_item', 'example value 1'),
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 128,
        '#description' => t('Nested Example Item'),
    );

    $form['unnested_example_item'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Unnested Example Item'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('unnested_example_item', 'example value 2'),
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 128,
        '#description' => t('Unnested Example Item'),
    );

    return system_settings_form($form);    }
```

Now what happens when i change both values and submit the form is the following:

- The unnested field behaves like expected - it reflects the changes.
- The nested field item, does not show this behaviour, does not reflect the changes

I am confused, should I treat the nested `variable_get` differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `system_settings_form()` only looks for variables defined at the root of the `$form_state['values']` array.

Since you have `'#tree' => TRUE` on your fieldset element this will not be the case. If you remove the `'#tree' => TRUE'` line, the value of your nested element will be saved in a variable called `'unnested_example_item'` as you expect.